# HTML JavaScript While Loop sentinel page unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html

Okay so I should create a program where the user inputs hours and the program will calculate charge based on hours. It should also display the total of all charges so I though I should use sentinel cause I dont have a specific number of inputs. When I put this while loop the page become unresponsive and when I remove it works fine but I can only input one. This is the code

```js
 window.addEventListener("load",start,false);
    function start(){
    document.getElementById("pagesa").addEventListener("click",llogarit,false);
    }
    function llogarit(){
    var ore=document.getElementById("ore").value;
    var ore=parseInt(ore);
    var shuma=0;
    var totali=0;
   while(ore!=-1)
   {
    if (ore<=3)
    {
    shuma=2;
    totali=totali+shuma;
    }
    else if (ore>3 && ore<=24)
    {
    shuma=10;
    totali=totali+shuma;
    }
    else
    {
    shuma=2+(ore-3)*0.5;
    totali=totali+shuma;
    }
    document.getElementById("rezultati").innerHTML = "Klienti ka paguar:"+shuma;
            document.getElementById("totali").innerHTML = "Totali eshte:"+totali;
    }
     
    }
```

```html
<label> Ore ne garazh </label>
    <input type="number" id="ore"/>
    <button id="pagesa"> Pagesa</button>
    <p id="rezultati"> </p>
    <p id="totali"> </p>
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop `while(ore!=-1)` and **ore** never becomes -1

Comment: I did that cause I want the program to keep calculating until I tell it to stop and I would pressing -1. Apparently its wrong. Any idea what should I place in the while loop condition

Comment: What do you mean from pressing -1?

Comment: I mean for example "ore" are inputed by the user and he can input any positive number (to clarify "ore" means "hours"). So the program should keep doing what is written inside the while loop as long as the input is different from -1 and when I input -1 the program should stop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat a function you have to use `setInterval(function,period)`  or `setTimeout` to call function within itself again not using a while loop! However I can not find why you are repeating that function when nothing is changed. If you have a time based calculation you have to update the time inside the function (but there is no time update). I have rewrote the function using `setTimeout` and embedded console to see that the calculator is called every 3 seconds.

```js
window.addEventListener("load",start,false);
     function start(){   
        document.getElementById("pagesa").addEventListener("click",llogarit,false);
     }
    function llogarit(){
      var ore=document.getElementById("ore").value;
      var ore=parseInt(ore);
      var shuma=0;
      var totali=0;
      if(ore!=-1){
      if (ore<=3){
      shuma=2;
      totali=totali+shuma;
      }
    
      else if (ore>3 && ore<=24) {
      shuma=10;
      totali=totali+shuma;
      }
    
      else{
      shuma=2+(ore-3)*0.5;
      totali=totali+shuma;
      }
    
      document.getElementById("rezultati").innerHTML = "Klienti ka paguar:"+shuma;
            document.getElementById("totali").innerHTML = "Totali eshte:"+totali;
          
     }
      
console.log('function repeated');
setTimeout(function(){llogarit()}, 3000);      
}
```

```html
<label> Ore ne garazh </label>
    <input type="number" id="ore"/>
    <button id="pagesa"> Pagesa</button>
    <p id="rezultati"> </p>
    <p id="totali"> </p>
```